# A chat bot to integrate to Microsoft Lync 2010/2013

Tags: lync, lync-2013, ucma, lync-client-sdk, lync-server-2010

I have created a chatbot in c# using .net 4.5. The chat bot accesses multiple other applications in the background and returns the output to the user.  The chat bot was initially planned to be a standalone application but the requirement has changed and now it needs to be integrated into Microsoft Lync. I searched for ways to do it and I found two things on the net that might be of some value to me:

1. UCMA - In this case I have to re-code my logic again. And installation and software requirements are currently not matching what is available with me currently.
2. MindLink - Would really love if someone shares a first hand experience on it. I am a little sceptical about it.

Is there a way to integrate the already coded chat bot with lync?

I know this is a little open ended question, but I would really appreciate if somebody shows me a proper way. Any help from the developer community would be much appreciated. In the meantime, I am continuing with my research and reading on it. I will update this question as and when I get something valuable.

Comment: Keep noted that there is also a UCWA (see differences [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193762/should-i-use-ucwa-or-ucma-or-another-api-for-a-skype-for-business-server-applica))

Comment: Use LyncClient SDK to integrate with lync if you need to extend your application from UCMA to Lync. But keep in mind that, if Lync Client SDK provides a house, UCMA provides universe.

Also keep in mind that; MSPL scripts are really useful if you would like to do something with incoming-outgoing requests to the server.

For example: Displaying different availability (available, busy, do not disturb etc.) for 1 Lync user's to all users.